# Where do I get libpq source?

Tags: postgresql

I want to write application which uses Postgresql as DBMS.
To write client application do I need libpq library and header files?
If yes where I would get libpq library and header files.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Libpq is included in the full PostgreSQL source code. You can use just libpq without the rest of PostgreSQL, but must download the full package.

You can download it from the [PostgreSQL Downloads page](http://www.postgresql.org/download/).

Once you extract the full package it is inside `src\interfaces\libpq`.

The [PostgreSQL installation guide](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/install-procedure.html#INSTALL) details how to install only the client libraries in the *Installation* section, under *Client-only installation*.

[Libpq documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq.html) is also available.

Answer (score 8):

In postgresql sources, src\interfaces\libpq.

And yes, it is possible to compile only the libpq.

Comment: Would you please detail how to download, compile & install only the libpq source on a server that DOES NOT have PostgreSQL installed. Thanks

Comment: I think my answer is self explanatory: download sources, extract, `configure`, cd to `src\interfaces\libpq`, `make`. Note, however, that I was doing this for a static library. Not sure if dynamic library can be build.

Comment: On this server, I ONLY want to install `libpq` NOT PostgreSQL. Won't running `configure` for the "extract" create a `Makefile` for the **ENTIRETY** of PostgreSQL?

Comment: You need to run `configure` in top dir of the source tree. This will create Makefiles for all components. Then you can step into library folder and execute `make` to build *only* the library. Google, and you'll find the answer.

Comment: Btw, some Linux distros has *libpq* as a separate package. For example, on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine I can install *libpq* via `sudo apt-get install libpq5`. This will work for all Debian based systems.

Comment: Thanks for the GREAT help, Andrejs.

Answer (score 6):

get the lipq from repo, {for debian} :

`sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`

Comment: you are assuming the op is using a Linux distro that uses APT

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing this issue but didn't got a clear answer:
This issue clearly states that while installing diesel-cli system is not able to locate `libpq.lib`

First of all you should have a Postgres installed on your machine.
Also diesel require visual c++, thus download and install it if not already, the size of setup will be ~5gb.
Once above installations are done you need to setup environment variables:

In my case path of Postgres installation is **`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL`** thus add 2 environment variable path under `User variables` add new in `Path` where your `libpq.lib` is located in my case it is available in both `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\lib` and `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin`

[image: Env variable]

Once this is added create one more environment variable **`PQ_LIB_DIR`** and set path as shown below

[image]

Note: **Once done re-trigger the installation command in a new cmd window**
Source: [pq-sys](https://github.com/sgrif/pq-sys) and [github-solution](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/487#issuecomment-538719967)

Answer (score 2):

For Windows users, it's in (version may be different)

```
 C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\lib
```

There you find `libpq.lib`. Provide this directory to Linker input. 
Don't forget to include `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\include` directory for include directories.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem reccently. This is a solution if you don't want to install Postgres in you windows.

At first, you need download [Postgres Binaries](https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries). The version I download is 13.6, but it's seems like any version is fine.

Unzip the zip file.Copy `libpq.lib` from `pgsql\lib` to shomewhere like `C:\Program Files\Postgres\lib`.

Execute the following command in cmd window.

```
setx PQ_LIB_DIR "{where_you_copy_to}"
```

Open a new cmd windows and install `diesel_cli`

```
cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

In linux vertify you get the libpq.
1st, there is an app: pg_config: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgconfig.html
after you found out the **pg_config absolute bin path**.(if you installed multi version of postgressql) Then You can get

```
--includedir
    Print the location of C header files of the client interfaces.
--libdir
    Print the location of object code libraries.
```

Then try to compile/build some example code: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-example.html
Some common failure example: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-build.html

Answer (score 0):

You can install Postgres locally from https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads but select only "Command line tools" for install.

After that, you can found libpq.dll in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin