# How to download, compile & install ONLY the libpq source on a server that DOES NOT have PostgreSQL installed

Tags: postgresql, installation, libpq

How can I download, compile, make & install ONLY the libpq source on a server (Ubuntu) that DOES NOT have PostgreSQL installed?

I have found the libpq source [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/src/interfaces/libpq). However it does NOT seem to be separable from the entire PostgreSQL. Thanks in advance.

I DO NOT want to install the entire PostgreSQL. I want to use libpq as a C interface to PostgreSQL on a DIFFERENT server (also Ubuntu) that DOES have it installed.

I also found [this old link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1244813/601770) which indicates that the above is POSSIBLE but not HOW to do it.

Answer (score 10):

> I have found the libpq source here. However it does NOT seem to be separable from the entire PostgreSQL.

It has to be configured with the entire source tree because that's what generates the necessary `Makefile` parts. But once configured, `make` && `make install` can run inside the `src/interfaces/libpq` directory alone, and the rest being left out completely.

In steps:

1. download the source code archive, for example https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v9.4.1/postgresql-9.4.1.tar.bz2
2. unpack into a build directory: `tar xjf ~/Downloads/postgresql-9.4.1.tar.bz2`
3. `apt-get install libssl-dev` if it's not installed already
4. cd into it and configure: `cd postgresql-9.4.1; ./configure --with-openssl --without-readline`
5. Assuming configure succeeds, cd into `src/interfaces/libpq` and run `make`
6. still in the `libpq` directory, run make install as root: `sudo make install`.

That will install into `/usr/local/pgsql` and subdirectories as a library independent and insulated from the one packaged in Ubuntu if it happens to be installed. To install it elsewhere, specify the location with the `--prefix` option to `configure`.

Comment: If only the OP would accept this answer as correct... @Loveandpeace ... FYI, details of the `--without-readline` option can be found [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/install-requirements.html).

Answer (score 5):

Besides downloading and configuration, the steps are:

```
cd src/interfaces/libpq; make; make install; cd -
cd src/bin/pg_config; make install; cd -
cd src/backend; make generated-headers; cd -
cd src/include; make install; cd -
```

These steps will give you the library and headers of `libpq`, and a binary called `pg_config`, and all postgresql backend headers, so that you could compile things like `libpqxx` correctly.

(I've just tested with postgresql-9.6.5.)

Comment: This looks short and sweet, does this still work for Postgres 12?

Comment: Looks ok on pg12, with your instructions I got me a `libpq.so.5.12`. Still not sure it's enough, the library I want to use is [taopq](https://github.com/taocpp/taopq)  (api looks cleaner and more like what I did in Python)