# SSL error when pushing postgres db to heroku

Tags: postgresql, ssl, heroku

I'm trying to push my local postgres db to heroku and I get the following SSL error:

> psql: sslmode value "require" invalid when SSL support is not compiled in

I uninstalled postgres and reinstalled it with the configuration

`./configure --with-includes=/usr/local/ssl/include`

I also changed the ssl setting in my postgresql.conf file to "on" and sent a SIGHUP signal to the server and still get the same error.

Is there something I'm overlooking?  I don't think it should be this difficult to push to heroku.

Comment: Please see the reason answered at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36201845/6723862.

Comment: And in case you're running on OSX then for less headache and more for your convenience check out: http://postgresapp.com/ :)

Comment: @KristoMagi I did see that answer.  I thought reinstalling postgres and configuring my setup with `./configure --with-includes=/usr/local/ssl/include` would result in my `libpq` library being configured correctly to work with openssl.

Comment: Might be then that you need to add `--with-openssl` and `--with-includes=/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl` flag – NB: check also folders. For another question what OS are you running and what did you use to install Postgres?

Comment: @KristoMagi I'm using OS X.  I installed postgres by downloading the source and following the instructions in the documentation.  I tried configuring my install by doing `--with-openssl` but got the error "configure: error: header file <openssl/ssl.h> is required for OpenSSL".  So i tried the solution here: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/5627D2A2.1020904@joeconway.com

Comment: Then maybe you want to try the PostgresApp as I commented before :)

Comment: I might resort to it.  But it would be nice to find out why I can't get this to work.

Comment: Understandable. Just to confirm – are your sure your openssl is at `/usr/local/..` ?

Comment: I just ran `openssl version -d` and the output was OPENSSLDIR: "/System/Library/OpenSSL" ...

Comment: Ack, that's where it stores stuff. But you may want to look into `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/[Some version number]/include/openssl/` when setting Postgres conf flags.

Comment: Found it.  `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2f/include/openssl`.  So you suggest configuring postgres by doing `./configure --with-openssl --with-includes=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2f/include/openssl`?