# R RPostgreSQL Connect to Remote Postgres Database with SSL

Tags: r, database, postgresql, ssl, rpostgresql

I am trying to connect to a remote PostgreSQL database from within R using the `RPostgreSQL` package, and I am getting errors that appear to be related to the SSL settings for the connection. I have verified that I can connect from the command line using `psql`, so I know the connection is valid and accessible from my computer.

My first attempt at connecting in R was the following (where `<MyHost>` and `<MyPass>` were filled out appropriately for my connection):

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
pg <- dbDriver( 'PostgreSQL' )
con = dbConnect( pg, host=<MyHost>, dbname='warehouse', 
                 user='warehouse', password=<MyPass>, port=5432 )
```

The error I received in R was:

```
RS-DBI driver: (could not connect warehouse@<MyHost>.com:5432 on 
dbname "warehouse": FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "75.166.243.177", 
user "warehouse", database "warehouse", SSL off
```

I understood this to mean that I needed to apply SSL encryption to my connection, and so I tried the following, which seems to have worked for the OP here: [Connect to Postgres via SSL using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989264/connect-to-postgres-via-ssl-using-r)

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
pg <- dbDriver( 'PostgreSQL' )
con = dbConnect( pg, host=<MyHost>, dbname='dbname=warehouse sslmode=require', 
                 user='warehouse', password=<MyPass>, port=5432 )
```

The error I received then was:

```
RS-DBI driver: (could not connect warehouse@<MyHost>:5432 on dbname 
"warehouse": sslmode value "require" invalid when SSL support is not 
compiled in
```

I found this post ([Postgres SSLMode Value "require" Invalid When SSL Support Is Not Compiled Using Foreign Data Wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186935/postgres-sslmode-value-require-invalid-when-ssl-support-is-not-compiled-using)) that suggested my build of PostgreSQL may not have had the `--with-openssl` flag included when it was compiled, but running pg_config revealed that this flag was indeed set in my build. This makes sense because I was able to connect to the database using SSL when I used the psql command line tool.

Fearing my PostgreSQL installation may be at fault, I completely removed it. I then ran both of the above snippets of R code, just for kicks, and I received exactly the same errors. I was not expecting this, but this seems to indicate that either (a) I do not need a local install of PostgreSQL in order to use the `RPostgreSQL` package or (b) I have a confounding install of PostgreSQL somewhere else on my computer that was *not* built with the `--with-openssl` flag included. I have tried `locate postgresql` at the command line and didn't see anything obvious that looked like a separate install. In any case, I still haven't been able to successfully connect to the remote PostgreSQL database from within R.

I've scoured Stack Overflow for insight here, and it seems there are a number of unresolved questions of a similar nature, where users are unable to establish connections with a remote server for some reason. I tried to install the RPostgres package that Kirill Müller is maintaining here (https://github.com/rstats-db/RPostgres), but I could not get the R package install to recognize my local PostgreSQL install, even after trying to specify the include and lib paths manually using `R CMD INSTALL`, as the resulting error message suggested (I may have missed something here though...). It sounds like some users have had better luck with `RPostgres` than with `RPostgreSQL`, but again, I wasn't able to install this package.

I'm at a loss for what else to do, and am going to have to resort to other technology if I can't figure out how to establish a connection soon. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's a bit more info. I ran `otool -L RPostgreSQL.so` for my installed `RPostgreSQL` package and the output pointed to `/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib` (`otool` is the Mac version of Linux's `ldd` to find libraries a binary is linked to). This is *not* the location of `libpq` from my install of Postgres.app, which is here: `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/lib/libpq.5.dylib`.

I don't know where the version in `/usr/lib` came from, but it appears it was not compiled with SSL support; this is what RPostgreSQL is using. How can I force `RPosgreSQL` to use the other `libpq.5.dylib`?

Comment: this seems like an older question, but still relevant.  I am trying to run the same connection command:  `library(RPostgreSQL)
pg <- dbDriver( 'PostgreSQL' )
con = dbConnect( pg, host=<MyHost>, dbname='dbname=<dbname> sslmode=require', user='<user>', password=<pass>, port=<port> )` and get the same "SSL support is not compiled in" error.  I do not have an `/Applications/Postgres.app`  directory and otool does not find RPostgreSQL.so

Comment: RPostgreSQL code shows a parameter, USE_SSL, that if it is not defined (https://github.com/cran/RPostgreSQL/blob/0e9b0cf002188f98258bd21a0d43d13c632a317c/src/libpq/fe-connect.c#L851) will result in the error message (https://github.com/cran/RPostgreSQL/blob/0e9b0cf002188f98258bd21a0d43d13c632a317c/src/libpq/fe-connect.c#L867).  How is USE_SSL defined/determined?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for posting! You actually helped us solve it. Here is how we did it:

- Reboot your Mac into Recovery Mode by restarting your computer and holding down <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> until the Apple logo appears on your screen.
- Click `Utilities` > `Terminal`.
- In the Terminal window, type in `csrutil disable` and press Enter.
- Restart your Mac.
- Open a Terminal.
- Run `sudo rm /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib`
- Run `sudo ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/lib/libpq.5‌​.dylib`
- Now you can connect to the DB.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is the requirement to turn off the Mac's System Integrity Protection (SIP) using `csrutil disable` so that the OS will let you remove `/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib`? That is, once I remove this file (or at least rename it until I'm sure I don't need it), can I run `csrutil enable` to re-enable SIP?