# Connect to Postgres via SSL using R on Windows

Tags: r, windows, ssl, rpostgresql

I'm trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database from R using SSL with the RPostgreSQL package (On windows).

```
dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL"), 
          user = user, 
          password = password, 
          host = host, 
          dbname = "dbname=dbname sslmode=require", 
          port = 5432)
```

But I get the following error :

```
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect user@host:5432 on dbname "dbname": sslmode value "require" invalid when SSL support is not compiled in)
```

I found a detailed thread on SO with a solution [R RPostgreSQL Connect to Remote Postgres Database with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030855/r-rpostgresql-connect-to-remote-postgres-database-with-ssl)
but unfortunately I can't try it on Windows.

Anyone knows how I can solve this issue on Windows ?

Comment: this might be relevant: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rpostgresql-dev/ELnVUJqjDbk but it also means that you are prob all on your own while using windows