# SSL error in R when I try and update my packages

Tags: r, ssl, installation, package

I am receiving the following error:

> Error: sslmode value "require" invalid when SSL support is not compiled in Execution halted Warning in install.packages :  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status

I get this error when I try to install the following packages:

```
 library(RPostgres)
 install.packages(c("broom", "cli", "data.table", "pillar", "pkgload", "quantreg",
                    "RcppParallel", "renv", "rmarkdown", "WriteXLS"))
```

I am running Rstudio(Version 1.3.1073) on MacOS 11.2.1 on the following machine:

```
Model Name: MacBook Pro
  Processor Name:   Quad-Core Intel Core i5
  Processor Speed:  2.4 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 6 MB
  Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled
  Memory:   8 GB
```

HELP??

Comment: When I paste a portion of the error message into Google, I get this as the first hit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186935/postgres-sslmode-value-require-invalid-when-ssl-support-is-not-compiled-using

Comment: Thanks that's one I haven't found.