# How build 64-bit version of libpq from source code?

Tags: postgresql, aix, libpq, xlc

I'm trying connect to PostgreSQL from C-code, and i have to build libpq from source, because i'm on AIX. I followed the steps in this comment 
[Where do i get libpq source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244778/where-do-i-get-libpq-source#comment47739449_1244813)
but in result i got a 32-bit version of libpq.a, how build 64-bit version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling on AIX is harder than on other platforms...
Always create a script which you gradually improve till you get a working version. Possible start:

```
#!/bin/sh

#assuming gcc
GCCLIB=$(dirname $(gcc -maix64 -pthread -print-file-name=libgcc_s.a))
export CFLAGS='-maix64 -mtune=native -pthread'
export CPPFLAGS='-D_GNU_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -D_ALL_SOURCE'
export LDFLAGS="-maix64 -Wl,-brtl -Wl,-blibpath:/usr/local/lib64:${GCCLIB}:/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -pthread"
export OBJECT_MODE=64

./configure --prefix=/usr/local \
    --libdir=/usr/local/lib64   \
    --enable-shared             \
    --enable-static             \
    2>&1 | tee log.configure

make all 2>&1 | tee log.make.all
make install 2>&1 | tee log.make.install
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if i want to use xlC, rather than gcc? Or is it impossible? 
I already know that i can not do without a gnu make.

Comment: Most certainly it is possible, but you have to search for the suitable options, for example use `-q64` instead of `-maix64`; also you have to remove the "GCCLIB"-parts

Comment: Perhaps you have to change `-pthread` to `-lpthreads` and explicitly set CC variable: `export CC=xlC_r`

Comment: Correction: `export CC=xlc_r; export CXX=xlC_r` (the case of letter c/C means C or C++)

Answer (score 0):

The -q64 compiler option enables 64 bit (there is info in the compiler docs)

A quick google search of xlC 64 bit gives this link which you might find helpful.

http://northstar-www.dartmouth.edu/doc/ibmcxx/en_US/doc/complink/tasks/tubld64a.htm