# Problems with setting up diesel for Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-diesel

I have the following problems:

If I execute the following command:
`diesel setup`
it throws me:
`requires the postgres feature but it's not enabled`
But my Cargo.toml looks like this:
`diesel = { version = "1.4.4", features = ["postgres", "r2d2", "chrono", "uuid"] }`

So now I thought well maybe I installed something wrong and when I try to run:
**cargo install diesel_cli -no--default-features --features postgres**

it tells me:
**linking with "link.exe" failed: exit code: 1181**

...
...
**"libpq.lib" cant be opened**

tried to reinstall, didnt work, thought it would work, gave me a new error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57178691/rust-link-failed-with-exit-code-1181

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55003832/diesel-error-linking-with-link-exe-failed-exit-code-1181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For linux ubuntu you need to install libq-dev

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev
```

For windows you need to either add postgres lib folder to env variables, for example:

```
PQ_LIB_DIR="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\lib"
```

or simply copy `libpq.lib` to

```
C:\Users\<username>\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib
```

Comment: copying libpq.lib to the desired/mentioned path worked for me.