# Problems connecting codeigniter 4 with postgres - CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException #8

Tags: php, database, postgresql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I want to make a project with codeigniter 4 and postgresql I have already seen several examples, I even read the documentation but it still shows an error when connecting to the database.

My file .env is like this:

```
# database.tests.hostname = localhost
# database.tests.database = postgres_test
# database.tests.username = test
# database.tests.password = test123
# database.tests.DBDriver = postgre
```

And my file config\App.php

```
public $tests = [
        'DSN'      => 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=database_name',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'test',
        'password' => 'test123',
        'database' => 'postgres_test',
        'DBDriver' => 'postgre',
        'DBPrefix' => 'db_',  
        'pConnect' => false,
        'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cacheOn'  => false,
        'cacheDir' => '',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swapPre'  => '',
        'encrypt'  => false,
        'compress' => false,
        'strictOn' => false,
        'failover' => [],
        'port'     => 5433,
    ];
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I understand that the .env file overwrites the config\App.php configuration, and gives me the error *CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException #8* and show *throw new DatabaseException('Unable to connect to the database.');*

Someone who knows more about the subject who can help me would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Having same problem. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Your .env file will overwrite the config/App.php settings. However you are setting the values on commented items.

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# database.default.hostname = localhost
# database.default.database = ci4
# database.default.username = root
# database.default.password = root
# database.default.DBDriver = MySQLi

# database.tests.hostname = localhost
# database.tests.database = ci4
# database.tests.username = root
# database.tests.password = root
# database.tests.DBDriver = MySQLi
```

All the values that start with **#** are commented. You need to remove it. However like you see there are two database groups. One for **running unit test** the other to run your app. The default one runs your app. That's the one you need to uncomment. Like so:

```
database.default.hostname = localhost
database.default.database = postgres_test
database.default.username = test
database.default.password = test123
database.default.DBDriver = Postgre
```

Note that I wrote the Postgre in uppercase as is that is how is referenced in the docs.

For more information on this subject you can find more here:

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html?highlight=env#configuring-with-env-file

Comment: I have uncommented only the default database group with settings and capitalized the Postgre part, but it still marks me CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException #8

Comment: Can you please add to the post what the exception said? Also, are you running codeigniter with the spark? If so, please check this forum thread: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-77463-post-379847.html

Comment: it sends me the message of CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException #8 and the exception throw new DatabaseException('Unable to connect to the database.'); I'm not using the spark, I should configure some of spark?

Comment: What are you running as a server?

Comment: I am working locally, I tried to run in CodeIgniter 3 and I get a _pg_connect () error: Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above_, do you know anything about that? I think the error comes from here, reading I found that I have to update my libpq but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Seems that you found the problem. My guess is that to update that would depend on your development environment.

Comment: maybe check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244778/where-do-i-get-libpq-source

Answer (score 2):

I used codeigniter 4 and postgres 10.

In the php configuration, make sure you enable the pgsql extension

[image: php.ini configuration]

then you can use this .env setting

[image]

or if you want to edit directly in the database.php configuration, leave the DSN blank

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 7.4+, did you try to connect to database without CI, to make sure you installed the database correctly?

You can try this to check the connection:

```php
# test_postgre.php

$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'yourdbname';
$user = 'yourdbuser';
$pass = 'yourdbpass';
$port = '5432';

$db_handle = pg_connect("host={$host} port={$port} dbname={$db} user={$user} password={$pass}");

if ($db_handle) {
    echo "\nConnection attempt succeeded. \n\n";
} else {
    echo "\nConnection attempt failed. \n\n";
}

echo "Connection Information\n";
echo "======================\n\n";

echo "DATABASE NAME:" . pg_dbname($db_handle) . "\n";
echo "HOSTNAME: " . pg_host($db_handle) . "\n";
echo "PORT: " . pg_port($db_handle) . "\n\n";
```

Then go to your terminal, and run:

```sh
php test_postgres.php
```

If you can put this file in your `public` folder, you can run from your browser also.